# Error Creating Ingestion Task in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to upload a DEM at 5 m resolution for a large area (province of NS) and file is around 8 gb. When I upload, everything seems to go fine until it reaches 100% and then says:

*Destination asset: /projects/ee-jrgallop/assets/NS_LiDAR_DEM_5m
Phase: Failed
Error: Error creating ingestion task (Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startsWith'))*

Any idea how to solve this?